# VL File Generator and EE 2.8

Tags: files

Is someone using VL File Generator with EE2.8? I've bought it these days, and it's not working (the file is not saved), even with all the correct settings:

```
URL: www.example.com/receitas/receitas_json
URL relative path: /receitas/receitas_json 
file relative path: /principal/json/receitas.json
```

The URL relative path contains this template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="receitas"}
        {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

the folder ot the file relative path is set to 777.

When a new entry is submitted in the channel or updated, no file is generated.
PHP safe_mode is turned off
Allow URL Fopen is turned on.

I’m using EE 2.8.1, and this problem is encountered too in the Wamp local server.

What could be the problem? A compatibility problem with EE 2.8?

Is there support yet for this extension? I contacted the author, no reply yet...

Comment: Exist support, great one!!! The problem com from a server config and not from VL file generator.

Comment: You should mark this as "solved" - I found it in the unanswered questions section... ;)

Comment: Hi Holland, thanks for the tip. How mark it as "solved"??